# Is $\{\{1\}\}\subseteq A$ true or false when $A=\{ 2, 3, 4, 5, \{1\}, 6 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please explain how you are supposed to think when you encounter questions like this:
$A=\{ 2, 3, 4, 5, \{1\}, 6 \}$

Is the following statement true or false:

1. $\{1\}\subseteq A$
2. $\{\{1\}\}\subseteq A$
3. $\{\{\{1\}\}\}\subseteq A$

I would say that the first is true and the other two are false. But I don't know for certain that it is correct and I also don't know how to explain why. Please help, thanks.

Comment: What does $\subseteq$ mean to you?

Comment: Can you explain why you downvote so I can improve.

Comment: @Arthur Is a subset to a set is what that means to me.

Comment: Why do you think that {{1}} is not a subset?

Comment: "Is a subset" is the name of the relation. There is also a definition; a _fundamental property_, if you will. Do you know what "is a subset" _means_ mathematically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S\subseteq A$ means that for every $x\in S$, we have $x\in A$. So now:

1. Is $1\in A$?
2. Is $\{1\}\in A$?
3. Is $\{\{1\}\}\in A$?

Comment: So 2 is true and 1 and 3 are false? Since {1} is an element but not the others.

Comment: @Sembfi: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** by the definition of subset, $\{x\}\subseteq A$ if and only if $x\in A$.

Answer (score 2):

using the axiom of pairing:
$\{x,y\}=w\iff (\exists w)(\forall x)(z \in w \iff z=x \lor z=y)$.
thus:
$\{x\}=\{x,x\}$.

every bracket indicates "belonging":

Thus:

$x\in \{x\}$.

$\{x\}\in \{\{x\}\}$.